# Comparing strings with alphanumerics - Java

Tags: java, sorting, interface, comparator

I'm implementing a `Java` class that compares strings with alphanumerics. For example, `"woot", "w00t"` will be returned as `"w00t", "woot"`.
This class implements the `Comparator` interface:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<CharSequence> {

    @Override
    public int compare (CharSequence s1, CharSequence s2) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\D*)(\\d*)");
        Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher(s1);
        Matcher m2 = pattern.matcher(s2);

        while (m1.find() && m2.find()) {
            int nonDigitCompare = m1.group(1).compareTo(m2.group(1));
            if (0 != nonDigitCompare) {
                return nonDigitCompare;
            }
             if (m1.group(2).isEmpty()) {
                return m2.group(2).isEmpty() ? 0 : -1;
             } else if (m2.group(2).isEmpty()) {
                return 1;
             }
             BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger(m1.group(2));
             BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger(m2.group(2));
             int numberCompare = n1.compareTo(n2);
             if (0 != numberCompare) {
                return numberCompare;
             }
        }
        return m1.hitEnd() && m2.hitEnd() ? 0 :
               m1.hitEnd()                ? -1 : 1;
    }
  }
```

For most cases the above code works fine. However, for the following `String[] arguments` it fails:

```
String[] arguments = {"p6.py", "p0007.py", "pa", "2016-05-02", "p.py", ".py", "10.20.30.40", "p9", "b"};
```

It outputs `"10.20.30.40, 2016-05-02, .py, b, p6.py, p0007.py, p9 ,p.py , pa"` 
instead of `".py, 10.20.30.40, 2016-05-02, b, p.py, p6.py, p007.py, p9, pa"`.

What's wrong with my `compare` method?

Comment: What is `this.pattern`?

Comment: @hotzst good catch! updating the question

Comment: Well, what would you expect a correct solution to be?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos that's shown in the question itself ... I gave the input array to be sorted, the actual output and the expected output.